# Regular expression to get an entire function from a shell script?

Tags: regex, bash, function, grep

I'm writing a small bash script and I need to read other scripts and search for specific functions in them so I can copy those functions from start to finish. I'm not an expert using grep, so I tried something like:

```
grep -E ".*() \{.*\}" file.sh
```

But it didn't work, and it also wouldn't get the entire function if it did, just the code between the first opening bracket and the first closing one.

So what would be a good regular expression for this? It doesn't necessarily have to use grep, I just figured it would.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the body of the function is enclosed in `{...}`. *Any* compound command could be used.

Comment: Moreover inner lines of the function may contain `}` as well.

Comment: Please add representative functions to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to reinvent wheel here. Bash naturally contains a parser to get the information needed. You could use `declare` (or `type`). E.g.

```
source file.sh
declare -F      # will print list of all declared functions
declare -f foo  # will print function definition for function foo
```

See `help declare` and `help type` for more information.

Comment: Oh, OK, that was easier than I thought. Thanks!